# Complex Index Match Only the Month and Year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Using a formula I'm trying to populate table 1
Like this
[image]

Conditions are:
-Matching only the month and year
-Combine all qty in the same month

I'm thinking something like index match with month()&year()...
Maybe there is a better formula on how to do this?

Comment: Are the headers `Jan-20` actual dates formatted `mmm-yy` or are they and actual text string?

Comment: Sounds like `SumIfs` would be more appropriate... sum quantity where where the month matches, the year matches, and the fruit matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the headers on Table 1 are dates formatted `mmm-yy`  The use this:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$F2,$B:$B,">="&EOMONTH(G$1,-1)+1,$B:$B,"<"&EOMONTH(G$1,0)+1)
```

[image]

---

If the headers are text then use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=$F2)*(TEXT($B$2:$B$7,"mmm-yy")=G$1),$C$2:$C$7)
```

[image]

Comment: I was just posting similar to this after making the comment about sumifs, thoguh I made columns for month and year in the table... completely forgot about end of month function (`eoMonth`)...

Comment: I couldn't understand the formula but it works.  
But say if the fruits are labeled apple 32, apple 31, apple 45 etc.,  
Can we add a formula so that it's looking up values before the space?
It's like a text to column delimited by a space

Comment: you would change `$A:$A,$F2` to `$A:$A,$F2 & " *"` in the sumifs.  In the sumproduct you would change `($A$2:$A$7=$F2)` to `(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F2,$A$2:$A$7)))` @GimGanDi

Answer (score 1):

Given a pivot table can (easily, dynamically and with versatility) return:

[image: ![PT exmple]

others with a very similar requirement my prefer a different solution.